# Cardinality of sets represented in storage

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently writing an API that implements abstract algebraic structures (sets, monoids, groups, etc). After discussing with a friend, we came to the conclusion that on a computer, the idea of cardinality of (in)finite sets isn't representable as far as we know. Say we have the following sets:

$$ A = \{a, b, c\} \land B = \{a, d, e\}$$

Both $A$ and $B$ have a cardinality of 3. If we take the union of these sets, we get:

$$ A \cup B = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$$

This cardinality of $ A \cup B$ is 5. If we take the intersection we get:

$$ A \cap B = \{a\}$$

The cardinality of this set is obviously 1. Say now that $B = \{d, e, f\}$. Suddenly, the union $A \cup B = \{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$, whose cardinality is 6 (analogously, the cardinality of the intersection is 0). This means that the contents of the set have an influence on the resulting cardinality (e.g. after taking a union of two sets). This is fine for sets where all the elements are known, but poses a problem for sets defined by a condition (i.e. $E = \{x | x \mod 2 == 0\}$). Is there a way of knowing the cardinality of such a resulting set, without generating a possibly infinite amount of elements (i.e. this would be an impossible problem to solve on a computer since the problem is intractable)?

Comment: If you allow set comprehension to define a set, it's not even computable whether or not a set is empty, i.e. cardinality zero.

Comment: That's the whole point. Is this problem truly non-computable, or are there methds to do this (non-logical/symbolic)

Comment: I'm not certain "this problem" is entirely well-defined, but it can probably be shown equivalent to Gödel-style completeness and the halting problem.

Comment: Assuming that ZFC (Zermelo, Fraenkel, Choice), the most common axiomatic base for modern set theory, is consistent, we may define $S=\emptyset$ if CH (the Continuum Hypothesis) and $S=\Bbb N$ if $\neg$CH. Then from ZFC we can prove there is a unique such $S$ but cannot prove nor disprove that $S$ is finite.